# how to implement push notification in android by using openmobster ?

Tags: android

I need to implement push notifications by using open_mobster on my project. i am trying implement open_mobster sample projects(notification and push-mail) but those are not satisfy my needs,i want to detailed step by step implementation push notification.

Comment: why exactly those examples do not satisfy your needs?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge on using open_mobster for implementation push notification.i want to push the notification to client mobiles whenever app server is raise the events,so the given sample examples are not for that angle.

Answer (score 2):

For detailed steps on integrating Push Notifications in your app may be take a look at the official documentation of the project published here:
http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/content/app-developer-guide/html/push.html

As far as Sample Apps go, I would recommend you look at the "CRUD" App. It covers both Sync based Push Notifications, and Push Notifications invoked via your Backend App. I recommend looking at the "Cloud Side" Code of the sample project. Looking at this you should be able to see your use case which is Pushing server events to client devices. It does the exact same thing in this component here:https://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.4-SNAPSHOT/trunk/cloud/dev-tools/sampleApps/crud/cloud/src/main/java/org/crud/cloud/crm/bootstrap/StartPush.java
You will have to modify it according to your own code etc...

The PushMail App is slightly advanced, needs configuration of an IMAP Server, etc...so you can probably get lost in those details.

Hope this helps you go in the right direction.

Thanks
Sohil
CEO, OpenMobster, Open Source MBaaS Platform

Comment: What is the advantage of openmobstar (friend suggested) ? compare to other REST API custom curser adaper, sync adapter with GCM? I got to know about 1>openmobster  2>REST API custom curser adaper, sync adapter with GCM?  confused which one select, which one to use it when ? scratching my head ! any help..

Comment: Is OpenMobster down I cannot access the site anymore?